# PySpark MLLib: Convert numerical to categorical

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I got a dataframe from a data repo which has a few features based on date such as

- a) the year like 2011 or 2012 in one column,
- b) monthnum like 1 to 12 in another column,
- c) weekdayNum like 1 to 7 in one column and
- d) some other derived columns like IsSunday or IsMonday (represented as 0 or 1) in another column.
- e) with some other numerical features etc. like house sale price.

```
The types of all these are IntegerType()
```

**Question 1**: To train a model should I convert these date related columns to categorical?

**Question 2**: How do I do this in PySpark MLLib? Would just casting the data type into StringType() be enough ? So I mean if monthnum is 1 then can I just convert to "1" with the following code? Will the ML algoes take/recognize it as categorical?

Or there is a better way to do it?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = df.witColumn("MonthNum", df["MonthNum"].cast(StringType()))
```

Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: no need type conversion, use VectorAssemeber + VectorIndexer (set maxCategories) should be enough for your task. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer

Comment: Thanks a lot jxc.

Comment: @jxc: One question regarding VectorIndexer. Let's say I have 35 features and only 20 of them is categorical - how can I use VectorIndexer to specify those 20?

Comment: This is where you need to specify `maxCategories`:  if `n_i` is the number of distinct values in the `i`'th categorical column(total 20), and you can just set `maxCategories = max(all n_i)`, then columns with less distinct values than this will be automatically converted into nominal features. However, if some of the numerical features have less distinct values than maxCategories, then process them separately.

Comment: Thank you @jxc. That is great. Can you shed some light on how to process the numerical features separately? I need to create the Vector with the features so how do I separate them and put them together in the Vector

Comment: since `InputCols` from VectorAssembler can take Vectors, so you can always use VectorAssembler+VectorIndexer to process all categorical features, and then use VectorAssembler again to merge the Vector created from the above categorical features with all numerical columns to generate the final `features` vector.

Comment: Thank you! Should I use VectorIndexer for "each" categorical column separately and then merge each into the VectorAssembler (like using an iterator)?

Comment: ideally, you should be able to do VectorAssembler + VectorIndexter in one shot for all columns. only when you can not separate categorical columns from numerical columns by setting `maxCategories`  does you have to do this in two steps.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the previous answers,if you want the ordinal nature of the date to be taken account into the model then you can try to convert the date into unix time stamps. The only catch is rather than the week number in your data  you will need a date. You can convert this using a simple udf. If it is possible for you to directly get the date then wonderful.
Once you have the data then you can do something like this:

```
df_new = df.withColumn("date_info",concat_ws("-",col('date'),col('month'),col('year')))

df_timestamp = df_new.withColumn("time_stamp",unix_timestamp(col('date_info'),format='dd-MM-yyyy'))
```

Now along with this time stamp, you can vector assemble the other continuous features also. It will also be nice to normalize all the features before you feed in the training. You can check the pyspark.ml.feature.MinMaxScaler()

Comment: Thank you @Raghu. I am not adding Date into the mix but definitely monthNum and weekdayNum. So (if I understood correctly and) if I stretch your logic on these columns, are you saying that these columns should be kept as Integer to get the ordinal nature of them? Or is it better to convert them to StringType to make them Categorical and the category values will take care of the inner nature of how they are influencing the outcome?

Comment: What I mean is if I convert 1 to "Jan" or "1" - then any yearly house price sales during January would probably still be baked into the outcome - does keeping it as 1 (as integer) make it better and will there be any extra gain by keeping the ordinal nature of it ?

Comment: I mean to convert your date information into unix time stamps . check this link : https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: I mean to convert your date information into unix time stamps . check this link : https://www.unixtimestamp.com/
So, every day in you rdata will be converted to a numeric value.
For ex, 20/01/2020  is 1579478400 and  21/01/2020 is 1579564800. This is why you may need a date or some default values. By this you are translating the increasing nature of the date in your data , then this will be factored in your model. But if you want the model to learn by categories such as sales in January or sales in a CW, then converting to category will be better